# Dropdown show below table in react-table

Tags: html, css, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a dropdown item which is td of the table. And it is show below the table.
I change z-index of each property of the dropdown but can not change.
[image]

Image is here.
[image]

Any one can help me

Update:
Code for dropdown list:

```
<motion.div className="relative text-[#4F4F4F]">
      <div ref={node}>

        <div
          onClick={toggleOpenMenu}
          className="flex items-center justify-between gap-1 px-4 py-3 border rounded cursor-pointer border-grayLight hover:border-primary smooth-transform"
        >

            <p className="text-gray">
              {showing?.measuredUnitName || textDefault}
            </p>

        </div>
      </div>

      <motion.div
        initial="exit"
        animate={isOpen ? "enter" : "exit"}
        variants={subMenuAnimate}
        className={`absolute right-0 w-full shadow-md mt-2`}
        style={{
          borderRadius: 5,
          backgroundColor: "#ECF1F4",
          transformOrigin: "50% -30px",
          zIndex: 1,
        }}
      >
        <div
          id="list-dropdown"
          className="smooth-transform z-999 flex w-full flex-col gap-1 bg-[#fff] pb-3 max-h-[250px] overflow-y-auto"
        >

        </div>
      </motion.div>
    </motion.div>
```

Code for Table:

```
<div className="w-full overflow-hidden">
      <table className="w-full" {...getTableProps()}>
        ... like tan-stack demo
      </table>
    </div>
```

That is my table using react-table of tan-stack

Comment: It's likely that your table is using`overflow-hidden`. You could try `overflow-visible` instead. Also, it would be helpful if you would include the relevant code in your question (see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: hi @EdLucas . There are many code so which code i can capture for this.

Comment: i have editted @EdLucas

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to EdLucas, the problem is in table, not in dropdown list. overflow-visible will solve the problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).